# C# XmlDeserializer / XmlElement different names

Tags: c#, xml

is there any Way to define multiple Elementnames to one Class?

My Root-Class

```
[XmlRoot("part")]
public partial class TERMINAL_Part
{
    public partTerminal terminal { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string version { get; set; }

}
```

My not working Terminal sub-Class

```
public partial class partTerminal
{

    [XmlElement("round")]
    [XmlElement("hf")]
    [XmlElement("box")]
    public partTerminalType Type { get; set; }

}
```

My XML Files. here we have different sub childs (hf, round, box, ...) But all childs have the same Sub-Elements.

XML File 1

```
<terminal>
    <hf>
        <part_number>4E0_035_603</part_number>
    </hf>
</terminal>
```

XML File 2

```
<terminal>
    <round>
        <part_number>4E0_035_603</part_number>
    </round>
</terminal>
```

XML File 3

```
<terminal>
    <box>
        <part_number>4E0_035_603</part_number>
    </box>
</terminal>
```

Comment: I assume this is intended really for deserialization? (If for serialization, how would you be able to instruct which element name to use?) That is, you just want to be able to read these XML files, not write them?

Comment: i will deserialization this XML Files. All othe part from this file will work. Currently i have defined multiple variables

[XmlElement("round")]
public partTerminalType round{ get; set; }
[XmlElement("hf")]
public partTerminalType hf{ get; set; }
[XmlElement("box")]
public partTerminalType box{ get; set; }

But i want all Childs in 1 variable. not different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`[XmlChoiceIdentifier]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to support the different variations of the XML file. It's a bit involved but here's a sample implementation for your use. Basically, we're going to be adding an `enum` for the different element names, and add an additional property to your `partTerminal` to flag which specific name to use. (but it won't be visible in the XML)

First, your `partTerminal` will look like this:

```
public partial class partTerminal
{
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("TerminalType")]
    [XmlElement("round")]
    [XmlElement("hf")]
    [XmlElement("box")]
    public partTerminalType Type { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public TerminalChoiceType TerminalType { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the addition of `TerminalType` and the `[XmlChoiceIdentifier]`. The use of `[XmlIgnore]` on `TerminalType` makes sure that it won't be included in your XML files.

We also need to add the `TerminalChoiceType` enum as follows:

```
public enum TerminalChoiceType
{
    round,
    hf,
    box
}
```

You can now serialize/deserialize it as normal. Note that you can discern what kind of tag was used in the XML file as `TerminalType` will be set automtically to the corresponding value. Vice versa, when serializing, if you want it to write as a `box` value, simply set `TerminalType = TerminalChoiceType.box` and the serializer will honour that.